# Ionic build time exception: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build, ionic2

**com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt**

Any idea why I am getting this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error while using below commands
ionic platform add android@6.1.2
ionic build android --device --release

$ cordova -v
6.3.1
$ ionic -v
2.1.7
$ node -v
v6.11.2
$ npm -v
3.10.10

This error doesn't come with android@6.2.3, but I face some other compatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue too yesterday. but now already solved.

1. First, you need to uninstall all build tools from sdk manager
2. Install the newest build tools from sdk manager
3. remove the android platform from your ionic project
4. add the android platform into ionic project